# Joining multiple tables and pulling most recent data from a specific table's column - MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
Select 
T1.Figures, 
T1.Numbers, 
T3.Name,
T4.DateTime,
T5.Information,
T1.LogTime

From Table1 as T1

JOIN Table2 as T2 on T1.Figures = T2.Figures and T1.Numbers = T2.Numbers
JOIN Table3 as T3 on T1.CustomerID = T3.ID
join Table4 as T4 on T4.Figures = T1.Figures and T4.Numbers = T1.Numbers
join Table5 as T5 on T4.HostID = T5.ID

Where T2.CurrentStatus = 101
```

101 is active.
The above script will give every active card with every DateTime and LogTime result.
But, how can I only pull the most recent DateTime and LogTime for all the active cards?

Comment: can you please give us a design of your tables as markdown: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#tables and your desired result.

Comment: You might have to use the Group by combined with Max/Min function.